# Principle Of Life

Tags: meaning, expressions

I would like to understand what is meant by this expression:

> ***I often asked myself, did the principle of life proceed?***

This sentence came in the following context:

> When I had arrived at this point and had become as well acquainted
>   with the theory and practice of natural philosophy as depended on the
>   lessons of any of the professors at Ingolstadt, my residence there
>   being no longer conducive to my improvements, I thought of returning
>   to my friends and my native town, when an incident happened that
>   protracted my stay. ***Whence, I often asked myself, did the principle of***
>   ***life proceed?*** It was a bold question, and one which has never been
>   considered as a mystery; yet with how many things are we upon the
>   brink of becoming acquainted, if

What is mean by the *principle of life* here? 
And how can this principle of life proceed?

There is a meaning underlying in this expression, but I can't understand it.

Comment: Give us some context.

Comment: Done. You can see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essential part of the question is in the interrogative.

Whence (adverb) : From what source

The author is saying that though he believed he had accomplished all that he could at his current position, he was still routinely plagued by a question regarding the source of life.

Considering he's discussing natural philosophy I would assume he's referring the source of life from abiotic material. In this case I would consider "principle" to not mean belief, but rather the foundation of something. The question, in my mind, is something like:

> What is the foundational source of life?

Comment: Does principle of life mean aim of life here?

Comment: @pentanol updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase you are asking about is really *Whence ... did the principle of life proceed?*.  In other words

> What is the source of the principle of life?

Comment: Why is this an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the *Whence*, otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Principle means beginning. It comes from Latin where it does not have an 'L'. In the Latin translation of Genesis *In principio creavit Deus caelum et terram.*
In the beginning God created heaven and earth.

Comment: No, _principle_ does not mean _beginning_. One of the meanings of Latin _principium_ was _beginning_, but that tells you approximately nothing about the meaning of any English word.